# Dojo and finding an element with no name and dynamic ID

Tags: input, dojo

Hey all is it possible for Dojo (version 8) to get an **input tag** without knowing the ID nor class so I can change the style of the input box? All input boxes (which I have 8) all have the same class name.

*Please note that I am unable to edit the code below on the web page. I can only use an "onShow" property*

```
<input 
  dojoattachpoint="textbox,focusNode,_aroundNode" 
  dojoattachevent="onblur:onBlur,onfocus:onFocus,onkeyup:onKeyUp" 
  id="2c6af1dc-80cb-44f2-864d-1fb00216895dF_SingleLine-widget" 
  name="" 
  class="dijitReset dijitTextBox notDojoDndHandle" 
  type="text" 
  tabindex="0" 
  aria-label="text" 
  width="auto" 
  value="" 
  aria-describedby="2c6af1dc-80cb-44f2-864d-1fb00216895dF_SingleLine-widget-placeholder"
  style="max-width: 2.5em; width: 90%;">

<span 
  class="dijitPlaceHolder dijitInputField" 
  id="2c6af1dc-80cb-44f2-864d-1fb00216895dF_SingleLine-widget-placeholder" 
  style="max-width: 2.5em; width: 90%;">
  Ex: Bob
</span>
```

I figured the easiest path would be to find **Ex: Bob** and then step back one element which would, in theory, be in the input box section then but I am unsure if/how to do that if it would even work in the first place.

Any help would be great! Thanks!

**Update:**

```
dojo.query("span.dijitPlaceHolder.dijitInputField").forEach(function(node, index, arr){
      if (node.innerHTML === 'Ex: Bob') {
          var foundIt = dojo.query(node).prev();

          dojo.addClass(foundIt, "testClass");
      }
});
```

It never puts **testClass** within the input class.

Instead of what I need it to do:

```
class="dijitReset dijitTextBox notDojoDndHandle testClass"
```

It still has this:

```
class="dijitReset dijitTextBox notDojoDndHandle"
```

Comment: on what event do you want it to be selected?

Comment: @AminJafari I just need to change the style and/or the class name of the *input* box.

Comment: ok then at least tell me which one (first, second, third, ...) do you want to be changed?

Comment: @AminJafari not really need to change it, just need to add another class to it at the end of the 3rd one.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the javascript file that backs the template? If so, you can just reference it from the attach point.

```
this.textbox
```

Although I'm not sure why you have so many attach points for your input object.

If that doesn't work then how do you uniquely identify your input boxes? Is it by the type of input? Is it by their position? If so, you can probably use dojo/query to work with this. You can find the documentation for dojo/query [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/query.html)

Comment: I'm currently trying to loop through all the **span.dijitPlaceHolder dijitInputField** but cant seem to get it?

Comment: Can you post code on what you're trying to do? Also, if that is truly a dojo textbox, then it usually has wrapper divs. Are you sure you're not trying to modify the wrapper divs as those are the ones that usually build the complete dojo textbox.

Comment: Updated my OP for you

Comment: Anymore help, richard?

Comment: Have you tried looking to see whether the query is returning the correct values? Or whether the node.innerHTML condition isn't matching correctly? This type of debugging will help greatly in narrowing down what the problem is.